# In Eclipse Images are not clickable?

Tags: android

Ive made a pretty simple wallpaper app and have used the same code before. I get no errors but for some reason my images are not clickable, Am I missing something could someone help... here is the code so far

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class Nflwallpapers extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageView display;
int toPhone;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    toPhone = R.drawable.azcard1;

    display = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.IVdisplay);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage4);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage5);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage6);
    Button setWall = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setwallpaper);
    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);
    image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    image4.setOnClickListener(this);
    image5.setOnClickListener(this);
    image6.setOnClickListener(this);
    setWall.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.IVimage1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.azcard1);
        toPhone =R.drawable.azcard1;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.azcard2);
        toPhone =R.drawable.azcard2;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.azcard3);
        toPhone =R.drawable.azcard3;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.azcard4);
        toPhone =R.drawable.azcard4;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage5:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.azcard5);
        toPhone =R.drawable.azcard5;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage6:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.azcard6);
        toPhone =R.drawable.azcard6;
        break;
    case R.id.setwallpaper:
        InputStream yes = getResources().openRawResource(toPhone);
        Bitmap whatever = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(yes);
        try{
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(whatever);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    }

}



};
```

Comment: what is the relation with Eclipse, here?

Comment: Try setting the clickable propery to true in the the xml layout. (also clickableintouchmode)

Comment: All Views can be clickable. I would put a log statement in your Switch statement to make sure that the view is indeed being clicked.

Comment: im running it on my phone and my button is clickable and according to the code the pics should be clickable but are not responding

Comment: found that I had it running on to low an api

Answer (score 0):

well everything seem to be ok with your class. check out your xml layout setting... the horizontalScrollView and the LinearLayout..